# Using AWK in a Perl script?

Tags: perl, awk

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
$variable = `grep -i "Text: Added to directory" '$FOO/result.txt' | awk '{print $6}' | tr -d "'"`
print $variable;
```

Output:

```
Text: Added to directory /path/to/directory/
Use of uninitialized value $6 in concatenation (.) or string
```

How can I fetch just "/path/to/directory" instead of "Text: Added to directory /path/to/directory/"?

Comment: Well at the least, you've got unbalanced quotes. You also don't seem to be actually grepping anything.

Comment: sounds like you should be using `sed` to extract the text between "Added to" and "Use of"

Comment: Why dont you use the perl way of doing this?

Comment: `grep -i '$FOO/result.txt'` -- you specified the file but no pattern -- what are you grepping for?

Comment: Why dont you use the perl way of doing this? open FILE, "$FOO/result.txt" or die $!; while(<FILE>){ if /.*?(\/.*)/{ print $1; } }. Hope that is right, tell me if I made mistakes, this comment window is so small, and it is not the accurate answer to your question.

Comment: @glennjackman: actually, I think the pattern specified was the file name, and standard input would be processed.  (But it probably isn't what was intended, regardless of how carefully I split hairs.)

Comment: I don't know perl but I think it's probably safe to say that if you're calling awk from perl you've missed the point!

Comment: There is a nice command-line utility `a2p` which converts `awk` expressions to Perl code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course Perl can do what grep, awk and tr can do.

```
open my $fh, "<", "$FOO/result.txt" or die "can't open file: $!\n";
while (<$fh>) {
    next unless /pattern/i;
    (my $six = (split)[5]) =~ tr/'//d;
    print $six, "\n";
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting not using external commands in Perl to... practically extract and report text. :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to adjust the quote-escaping but this should do:

```
awk IGNORECASE=1 '/yourpattern/{ gsub(/\'/, \'\'); print $6 }' $FOO/result.txt
```

AWK is pretty versatile.